# SSRS report flashes but won't show anything on report server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report to modify on SSRS (just to add a new column for the table that was created using a custom code function). The table was created using natural key and create "case". I added the natural column for the keys and when I previewed it in SSRS, everything looked perfect! However, when I uploaded it to the server, the report can only select partial selections from a drill-down field/widget. If I choose "select all" for the parameters, it flashes then nothing happens (neither an error message nor data is shown).

It was running fine and I was able to select all the selections for the report in Visual Studio and even extract it in Excel. I thought it was a credential problem, so I used my ID and password for the credentials, but it still did not work.

I tried to deploy the original report that was downloaded from the server, but it wasn't working (even without any changes).

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing when you change a parameter the other parameters refresh, which causes the screen to "flash", but it doesn't refresh the results pane.   You have the click the "View Report" button for that to happen.

Comment: I did click see the report running fine In "view report" but not after deploying it to report server

Comment: Try using profiler to see what is being sent to your SQL server when you encounter this problem on report server.